# main view keeps redirecting to login page even for logged-in user in django

Tags: django, authentication, nginx, redirect

my main view is,

```
def main(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request,'main/main.html',{'use':use,'query':query,'noter':noter,'theme':request.user.profile.theme})
else:
    return redirect('home')
```

the home page is responsible for serving login form is

```
def home(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('main')
else:
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

the "home.html" uses ajax to submit login page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form2').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#username_error').empty();
    $("#password_error").empty();
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    var formdata={
        'username':$('input[name=username2]').val(),
        'password':$('input[name=loginpassword]').val(),
    };



    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/Submit/logging',
        data:formdata,
        dataType:'json',
        encode:true,
        headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
    })

    .done(function(data){

        if(!data.success){//we will handle error
            if (data.password){
                    $('#password_error').text(data.password);
            }
            if(data.Message){
                $('#password_error').text("You can't login via pc");

            }
            blocker();


            return false;

        }
            else{
                window.location='/';
            }

    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

this configuration is working fine but main page keeps redirecting to home.html even when though user is already logged in. I'm using nginx server whose configuration is

```
server {
server_name host.me www.host.me;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
        root /home/username/projectname;
}


location /media/ {
        root /home/username/projectname/appname;
}


location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/projectname/projectname.sock;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.host.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.host.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}server {
if ($host = www.host.me) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = host.me) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name host.me www.host.me;
return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

**Edit 1**
The urls of corresponding views are,

```
path('home',views.home,name='home'),
path('',views.main,name='main'),
path('Submit/logging',views.Loging,name='Loging'),
```

while my view for performing login is

```
def Loging(request):
if request.user_agent.is_pc:
    return JsonResponse({'Message':'pc'})
else:
    username1=request.POST['username']
    print(username1)
    username=username1.lower()
    password=request.POST['password']
    print(password)
    user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return JsonResponse({'success':True})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'password':'The user credentials do not exist in our database'})
```

Also if a user tries to access website from another url endpoint(say mywebsite.me/another) & already authenticated , then it will lead to the correct view which means login is performed correctly.

Comment: You need to show your URLs and the "Submit/logging" view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman please check my edit.Also the same code is working in development but not in production environment. My take is that i'm missing something in nginx configuration which may be required for redirect

Comment: @DanielRoseman you can check the project at https://saporasocial.me

Comment: @DanielRoseman  also this error is only encountered when i'm using duckduckgo, firefox lite,via